# Style a DataTable with bottom borders only on some header/footer rows

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a cashflow app and would like to show a table but with borders only used to delineate a header or subtotal column.

DataTable seems to be all or nothing for border styles. Is there any row-by-row customisation possible?

[image: Goal]

[image: Current]

Comment: Did you get any solution to this? I've been trying to implement this exact thing but no luck

Comment: No I think I'll have to use a different way to do the tables

Comment: @thedarthcoder I got the look I wanted from a Table widget.